# My Boost regular expression is not matching anything

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I'm trying to match strings which look like this:

Mar 25 19:17:55 127.0.0.1 user:[pool-15-thread-17]INTOUCH;0;INFO;SOFTLOADSERVICE;Install started

with a regular expression. Here is my code defining the regular expression:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
const std::string softload_startup = "(\\w{3}) (\\d{1,2}) (\\d{2}): 
(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})*SOFTLOADSERVICE;Install started\\s"; //NOLINT

const boost::regex softload_start(softload_startup);

class InTouchSoftload {
 public:
   explicit InTouchSoftload(std::string filename);
 private:
    std::string _log_name;
    std::tuple<unsigned int, std::string> software_update_start;
};
```

I am calling it here:

```
 int main() {
        fin.open(input_file);

        if (fin.fail()) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to open " << input_file << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }

        while (std::getline(fin, line)) {
                line_no++;
                if (regex_match(line, softload_start)) {
                    std::cout << line << std::endl;
                }
            }
        return 0;
    }
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get any matches. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `(?s)(\\w{3}) (\\d{1,2}) (\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}).*SOFTLOADSERVICE;Install started`

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is a really good tool to debug regular expressions

Comment: 'code' (?s)(\\w{3}) (\\d{1,2}) (\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}).*SOFTLOADSERVICE;Install started isn't giving me any expressions :/

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve] - we do not see which function you used, what flags you passed etc.

Comment: nromer: Continuing what @Slava says - write a tiny program with your regexp and a `main()` function which matches a particular string which you expect to be matched, but isn't (put it in a string constant). Update your question with that code.

Comment: @nromer [It should](https://regex101.com/r/4zPVHv/1).

Comment: The regex given does not match the sample line provided.

Comment: Why use boost when there is std::regex...

Comment: I need to for a school assignment. I am trying to find the correct regex for the sample line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your regular expression does not match the string you wanted it to match then your regular expression is wrong. I've corrected your regular expression:

```
(\\w{3}) (\\d{1,2}) (\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}).*SOFTLOADSERVICE;Install started\\s*
```

Here's where you can test your regular expression and yourself:

https://regex101.com/

https://www.regextester.com/

[https://regexr.com/](http://%20https://regexr.com/)

Comment: thank you, this seemed to work. as I mentioned its my first time working with boost regex and regular expressions in general, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

While you haven't provided a complete example, your recent edit suggests you're failing because you're trying to match individual lines - the result of `std::getline()`, while your pattern involves two lines.

If that's indeed the case, you should probably do one of the following:

- Match pairs of consecutive lines (i.e. at every iteration try matching the previous+current lines)
- Split the regexp into 2 regular expressions, one for each line. Now, whenever a line matches the first regexp, try matching the next line to the second; otherwise try matching it to the first.
- Add `^` to the beginning of your regexp and `$` to the end (so that it matches on line boundaries, and match your regexp against the entire input stream instead of line by line.

Comment: thanks for the heads up, where am I attempting to match multiple lines? I'm sorry I am new to the boost regex library (first assignment with it). I have done my best to look up the documentation for it and thought \w{n} would match n alphanumeric characters, which \d{n} would match n digits. the expression I am trying to match is just one line, it is shown as two because I ran out of room to type in? My formatting my be off, I will try to fix it.

Comment: @nromer: `std::getline()` gets you, well, a line.

Comment: I'm sorry if my post was unclear, I am indeed trying to match just a single line. I tried to edit my initial post to make that a bit clearer.

Comment: @nromer: Ah, but your regexp has a newline literal in it!